# Multiple apps, paid Dynos

Tags: heroku

Looking for best practice/implementation thoughts:

I often create small to medium web apps for client projects, usually webservices for mobile apps, sometimes websites.

Since the free Heroku model scales down/shuts down dynos if no activity is detected, the start up time of websites and web service calls are sometimes delayed.

I would like to pay monthly for 1-2 dynos so that the apps are available immediately, but I would like all my apps to use the same dynos.  Does anyone one if this is possible and where should I start.

I'm looking for solutions other than pinging the apps to try to keep the dynos alive, i'm not even sure if this really works in the long term.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't say what you're hosting, but this is generally not how Heroku works. If you want availability, you should probably pay for it, or ping the site to keep it up.

Comment: Yeah, I host a range of services, mainly web service APIs, but some websites.  I have since learned that individual apps is really the only way. a scheduled ping is ok as well.  Lastly, I have not problem paying for it, I just did not want to pay for each app, when really 1-2 dynos would work great for all my services.